Troubleshooting Marketing Cloud Connected Apps Authentication Errors
Lately we've been encountering every few days the same error in the activity log within Contact Builder/Data Sources for the MC connector:

The error comes and goes every few days with the same description with no apparent reason.
Between the errors the connector seems to work without any issues. But 60 minutes from the time an error is logged, some of the synchronized DEs stopped syncing. Then after 60 minutes everything goes back to normal.
Notice we did not make changes in the MC connector config and it has been working without any issue for a long time.
Does anyone have any idea how to prevent those errors?
Thanks
